# Was the "Iron Man" video phone technology ever used in real life?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, realism, iron-man

At the very beginning of *Iron Man* (2008) (and in other parts of the movie), we see Tony Stark, inventor of technology so advanced he can create a suit that builds itself, using a phone with a flip-out video screen.

Was this technology ever in use in real life? I know phones had pretty rudimentary cameras back then, but I don't recall any having this capability. Just curious if it actually existed or if it was made up for the movie.

[image: screencap of Tony Stark using the phone described above]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes**

Identical or very similar technology existed at the time the movie was made.

The phone is very likely to be the [LG VX9400](https://www.phonearena.com/phones/LG-VX9400_id1755) which is similar in style and was launched in January 2007 which makes it feasible that it was used in filming.

[image: LG VX9400]

(from [user guide pdf](https://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/pdf/VX9400_QSG.pdf))

The [wikipedia page on this phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_VX9400) makes the claim that it was the one used in the movie.

As does this [PC Magazine article](https://www.pcmag.com/news/super-phones-of-the-superheroes#iron-man-2008-lg-vx9400)

You can see the silver keyboard and the LG logo on this screencap

[image]

There were several phones pre the iPhone (and other devices with good touch screen technology) that had sliding or rotating screens which uncovered a keyboard allowing a large(er) screen and keyboard in a small device. The use of a device like this didn't strike me as being out of the ordinary for the time.  It appeared (like his high-end Audi cars) to be product placement rather than future-tech.

Answer (score 4):

The [Samsung Z130](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_z130-pictures-1051.php) (released in 2005) seems very close in design.

[image: Samsung Z130]

<sup>Image source: https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_z130-pictures-1051.php</sup>

It is clearly not the same model, but looks close enough for me to answer **YES**.

Comment: Interesting.  https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_z130-pictures-1051.php  I recall it had a Verizon logo on it, I'll have to watch it again and see if the buttons look the same.  Never knew this existed.  Released in 2005, Iron Man came out 2 years later.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Actually, I used that flip phone in 2006: ‘Cyon KH-1400’. (Cyon is a retired mobile phone brand under LG.)

[image: Cyon KH-1400]

Comment: I don't think it is the KH-1400, unless there is a variant with silver color (particularly they keypad) since shots of Tony using the phone show it to be more like the LG.  I wonder if they are related designs.